# How can I use the hook's value from one jsx to other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am making a cart and when I click `Add to cart` then the number of times increases this is done using hooks and is in the following Pricetag.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import { useState } from 'react'
// import './Cart.js'
export default function Pricetag(props) {
  const [count, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card1">

        <div className="image">
          <img src={props.images} alt="" className='card-image' />
        </div>

        <div className="content">

          <div className="name">
            {props.name}
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className="button">
          <button className='btn no1' id='cartbutton' onClick={() => setCartCount(count + 1)} >
            Add to cart 
          </button>
          <br></br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Now I want to use the value of count in other jsx,

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import image2 from './assets/cake9.jpeg'
import image9 from './assets/cake16.jpeg'
import Pricetag from './Pricetag'
export default function Body(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="headingbody">
        <div></div>
        {props.title}
      </div>
      <div className="cart">
              <div className="number34">  ** here I want to show my count **</div>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
      </div>
        <hr className='latestline' />
      <div className='container1'>

        <Pricetag images={image10} name="Swimming cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
        <Pricetag images={image11} name="Rossy cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
      </div>

    </>
  )
}
```

Can you tell me how can I use the value of count from the first to the second?

Comment: Then you have to use redux.

Comment: You definitely do not have to use redux.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can use:

- state management: redux, zustand,...
- using React Context
- you can pass the value through props but it will cause 'hell props'

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the **count** state to the other JSX file (component). There are some ways:

1. Import the JSX file and call the component inside Pricetag.jsx, then pass **count** as a prop.
2. If you are unable to use the component inside Pricetag.jsx, then Use state management solutions like Context API, Redux, MobX etc.

Answer (score 0):

brother, you can find the description and idea from the below document of **useContext API** calling and its functionaloty

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-usecontext-hook/

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext